# Use configuration properties in apache camel route

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

Is it possible to use concated strings in a apache camel route? Property placeholders work fine but concatation doesn't work.

If tried something like this but the route doesn't pass the data.

*dependencies*

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.3.RELEASE",
"org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:2.23.1",
"org.apache.camel:camel-paho:2.23.1",
```

*application.properties*

```
a.b.property1=test
a.b.property2=test
```

*RouteConfig*

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "a")
public class RouteConfig{
   private B b;

   public B getB() {
        return b;
   }

   public static class B {
       private String property1;
       private String property2;

       public String getProperty1() {
          return property1;
       }

       public String getProperty2() {
          return property2;
       }
   }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Route extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    RouteConfig routeConfig;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("paho://" + routeConfig.getB().getProperty1()).to(direct:foo)
    }
}
```

Apache camel should build the route with a string which is build with concatination.

Comment: Can you tell more about what you are using? Is it spring boot or what's those configuration annotation coming from? And what version of Camel do you use? And what string does the "from" in your Camel route end up being built as? And frankly it looks more of a Spring issue than Camel as its appears to be spring configuration that you attempt to autowrite

Comment: Yes I'm autowiring a spring configuration which I want to use to build my from uri. The string is build correctly but the data from this route doesn't get forwarded to the to uri. If I hardcode the uri everything works fine. I added the versions and the necessary dependecies to my post.

Comment: Well then the whole property stuff seems to work. Do you get an error message? Or how do you know it "doesn't get forwarded"? Have you tried to concat the `from` outside the route and use the complete string in `from()`?

Comment: I checked it with integration tests. Yes I tried that. I also tried `String.format()` instead of string concatenation. If I check the logs the route gets started correctly but no data arrives. After intenst testing I suspect that I have a misconfiguration somewhere and the code works fine.

Comment: This code works fine. I found a misconfiguration in another part of the code.